# Node run multiple instances and close only requested instance

Tags: node.js

I am using xvbf in node application to run a chrome client for capturing web site screens in background. From a web page i am passing data to my webservice as at the bottom of this code part to START_CAPTURE and STOP_CAPTURE.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const Xvfb      = require('xvfb');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
const os = require('os');
const homedir = os.homedir();
const platform = os.platform();

const http = require('http');
const StringDecoder = require('string_decoder').StringDecoder;
const http_port = 8000;
const ffmpegServer = config.ffmpegServer + ":" + config.ffmpegServerPort;

var xvfb        = new Xvfb({
    silent: true,
    xvfb_args: ["-screen", "0", "1280x800x24", "-ac", "-nolisten", "tcp", "-dpi", "96", "+extension", "RANDR"]
});
var action = "";
var width       = 1280;
var height      = 720;
var options     = {
  headless: false,
  args: [
    '--enable-usermedia-screen-capturing',
    '--allow-http-screen-capture',
    '--load-extension=' + __dirname,
    '--disable-extensions-except=' + __dirname,
    '--disable-infobars',
    '--start-fullscreen',
    '--app=https://www.google.com/'`
  ],
}
options.executablePath = "/usr/bin/google-chrome"

async function main() {

        try{
            if(platform == "linux"){
                xvfb.startSync()
            }

            var exportname = 'video.webm'
            var url = 'https://www.google.com/';
            var duration = 30;

            const browser = await puppeteer.launch(options)
            const pages = await browser.pages()

            const page = pages[0]

            page.on('console', msg => {
                var m = msg.text();
                console.log('PAGE LOG:', m)
            });

            await page._client.send('Emulation.clearDeviceMetricsOverride')
            await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'})
            await page.setBypassCSP(true);

            if(duration > 0){
                await page.waitFor((duration * 1000))
            }else{
                while(action!="STOP_CAPTURE"){
                    try {
                        await page.waitForSelector('[class^=modal] > [class^=content] > button[description="Logs you out"]', {
                            timeout: 1000
                        });
                    } catch (err) {
                        // Do nothing
                    }
                }
            }

            await page.close()
            await browser.close()

            if(platform == "linux"){
                xvfb.stopSync()
            }

            fs.unlinkSync(homedir + "/video.webm");

        }catch(err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
}



// Instantiate the HTTP server.
const httpServer = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    if (req.method == 'POST') {
        var jsonString = '';
        var buffers = [];

        req.on('data', function (chunk) {
            buffers.push(chunk);
        });

        req.on('error', (err) => {
              // This prints the error message and stack trace to `stderr`.
              console.log("Error: %s \n" + err.stack);
        });

        req.on('end', function () {
          try {
            jsonString = JSON.parse(Buffer.concat(buffers).toString());
            var action = jsonString.markers[0]['action'];
              if(action=="START_CAPTURE"){
                  main();
              }
          }
          catch(e) {
            jsonString = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Buffer.concat(buffers).toString()));
            console.log('\nError \n ' + JSON.stringify(jsonString));
          }
        });
    }

    res.end();
    console.log('Response ended here. \n ');
});


httpServer.listen(http_port, () => {
  console.log("Web server is listening on port %s \n", http_port);
});
```

This is how it works.

I am clicking a button (START_CAPTURE) from my web site to start capturing. Then capture start. Then i am clicking a button (STOP_CAPTURE) to stop capturing. 
everything is working fine. If i do like this.

But if i click START_CAPTURE using two different browsers, then i clicked on STOP_CAPTURE button from any browser window, both instances are getting stop.

I know it is happened because of this lines.

```
               while(action!="STOP_CAPTURE"){
                    try {
                        await page.waitForSelector('[class^=modal] > [class^=content] > button[description="Logs you out"]', {
                            timeout: 1000
                        });
                    } catch (err) {
                        // Do nothing
                    }
                }
```

Is there anyway to stop only requested instance ? How can i achieve it ?

Comment: Well, you have only one module variable called `action` that both invocations of `main()` are watching.So, when you change that variable, both instances of `main()` see that.  You will need to keep track of which instance is which and tell only the correct one to stop. Probably it is simplest to assign an id for each client somehow perhaps in a cookie or even embed a random number in the start request that is sent back with the stop request. Then, when you get the stop, you can at least know which id you want to stop. Then each instance has to look at its own stop identifier, not the same one.

Comment: It would also help if you show the code for processing the stop button.  I don't see that code in your question.